# poll() POLLIN events on udp socket in C

Tags: c, linux, sockets, unix, udp

i am trying to implement an UDP-UART bridge with poll. The programm works fine, but i think the POLLIN events are triggered when i receive something but ALSO when i send something ...

```
        fds[0].fd = port; // configure fdset 0 on uart 
        fds[0].events = POLLIN ; // we are interested by POLLIN events type

        fds[1].fd = socket; // configure fdset 1 on udp socket
        fds[1].events = POLLIN ; // we are interested by POLLIN events type

while(1) // main process loop
        {
            ret = poll(fds,2, timeout_msecs); // check the two fds for events (uart & socket)
            if (ret > 0) { // if there is an event

                if (fds[1].revents & POLLIN) // if the event is an input on socket fds[1]
                {
                    sock_length = recvfrom(socket,&sock_buff,sizeof(sock_buff),MSG_WAITALL, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, &fromlen); //receive from socket and store tosock_buff

                    write(port,sock_buff,sock_length); // send  back sock_buff content through uart





                }



                if (fds[0].revents & POLLIN) // if the event is an input on uart fds[0]
                {
                    ser_length = read(port, ser_buff, sizeof(ser_buff) ); //read the uart and store to serbuff

                    sendto(socket,ser_buff,ser_length,MSG_CONFIRM, (const struct sockaddr *) &servaddr,sizeof(servaddr)); //send the serial buffer via udp socket





                }


            }
            else  // if nothing append before "timeout_msecs" milliseconds (5000)
            {
                printf("timeout \n");


            }
```

here my code, the problem i got is the following :
let's imagine i got something on the uart side for example "hello server" then i use sendto to send the string via the socket. but i think it  trigger a POLLIN event on the socket. so it will write back in the uart the data i just send like an echo...

when i send "hello server" i want to get back in the uart the answer of the server "hello client"

but currently i got "hello server hello client" because  the socket POLLIN event is trigerred two times, when i send , and when the server answer

is there a way to prevent the POLLIN from being triggered when i use "sendto" ?

Best regards,

pierre.

edit: the socket is initialized this way :

```
struct sockaddr_in servaddr;

int open_connection(char * IPaddr,unsigned int port)
{
    int sockfd = 0;
    if (( sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0 ) 
    { 
        perror("socket creation failed"); 
        return -1;
    } 
    memset(&servaddr, 0, sizeof(servaddr)); 
    // Filling server information 
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET; 
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(port); 
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(IPaddr); 

    return sockfd;

}
```

Comment: Remember that [`poll`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) modifies the structures in the array you pass, and you need to reset it before each call.

Comment: Also remember that `ret` could be `-1` in case of error (other than timeout where `ret` will be zero).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude `poll()` only modifies `revents`. You don't have to reset anything.

Comment: How is `servaddr` initialized? Please provide more code context, with the code available the behaviour is not explainable imho.

Comment: Did you observe it in the debugger?

Comment: @Ctx i added the initialization code in the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finnally solve my problem. It was not related to udp socket neither poll().

in fact,when you configure an uart under unix you have to explicitly block the echo input parameter.

```
config.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO | ECHOE | ISIG); // disable echo et signals
```

if don't do this the local uart echo will send back your data.

Sorry for waste your time.

regards,

Pierre.